# Parameter not populating from Ajax call (Tried everything)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Good day everybody.

I have a simple `Ajax` call. In simplicity, it reads a password from a password field, populates it into a variable, and then sends it across to my StrengthCheck controller. So everything is working perfectly the ajax call makes it into the StregthCheck ActionResult and the ajax success section is fired off hunky-dory. However, the parameter `Password` in my StrengthCheck actionResult won't populate with the password sent from my ajax call. I truly believe I've tried everything, any input would be greatly appreciated whether it's a possible solution or even advanced tips to debugging.

Thanks so much in advance, hoping to keep this question as simple as possible.

### Script

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Password").change(function () {
            debugger
            var password = $("#Password").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("StrengthCheck", "Login")',
                data: { Password: password },
                dataType:'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#PasswordStrength").val(result);
                    if (result.PasswordStrength != "Blank" && result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        var lblStatus = document.getElementById("PasswordStrength");
                        lblStatus.style.width = result + "%";
                        switch (result)
                            {
                                case "20":
                                    $("#PasswordStrength").removeClass("progress-bar-success").addClass("progress-bar-warning");
                                    break;
                                case "40":
                                    $("#PasswordStrength").removeClass("progress-bar-success").addClass("progress-bar-warning");
                                    break;
                                case "60":
                                    $("#PasswordStrength").removeClass("progress-bar-warning").addClass("progress-bar-success");
                                    break;
                                case "80":
                                    $("#PasswordStrength").removeClass("progress-bar-warning").addClass("progress-bar-success");
                                    break;
                                case "100":
                                    $("#PasswordStrength").removeClass("progress-bar-warning").addClass("progress-bar-success");
                                    break;
                            }

                        }


                    },
                error: function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqxhr);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);

                },
                    async: true,
                    processData: false

            });

        })



    });



</script>
```

Login Controller

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult StrengthCheck(PhysiotherapyDAL.ViewModels.PasswordResetViewModel data)
        {
            #region password strength
            PasswordScore passwordStrengthScore = PasswordAdvisor.CheckStrength(data.Password); 

            switch (passwordStrengthScore)
            {
                case PasswordScore.Blank:
                    data.PasswordStrength = 0;
                    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.PasswordStrength), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                case PasswordScore.VeryWeak:
                    data.PasswordStrength = 20;
                    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.PasswordStrength), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                case PasswordScore.Weak:
                    data.PasswordStrength = 40;
                    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.PasswordStrength), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                case PasswordScore.Medium:
                    data.PasswordStrength = 60;
                    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.PasswordStrength), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                case PasswordScore.Strong:
                    data.PasswordStrength = 80;
                    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.PasswordStrength), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                case PasswordScore.VeryStrong:
                    data.PasswordStrength = 100;
                    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.PasswordStrength), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                default:
                    break;
            }
            #endregion
            data.PasswordStrength = 0;
            return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.PasswordStrength), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

PasswordResetViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PhysiotherapyDAL.ViewModels
{
   public class PasswordResetViewModel
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm password required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The two passwords do not match. Please ensure they match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public string ResetCode { get; set; }

        public string UserID { get; set; }
        
        public bool success { get; set; }

        public int PasswordStrength { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of chrome debugging showing the population of data throughout the ajax call
[Screenshot of chrome debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2CU5.png)

Comment: Just for giggles, try a different name, eg `string thePassword` and `data: { thePassword : password },`  (there's *something* that tells me "password" parameter is reserved name and handled by mvc differently)

Comment: your edit *StrengthCheck actionResult* is a little odd - you don't have password in your *result*

Comment: Also, as your result is just an int, why not just return the ActionResult int?

Comment: If the issue is with the return value, try `return Json(new { PasswordStrength }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`  - `return Json(...` serialises the result for you, so you're serialising twice

Comment: Perhaps off topic: `if (result.PasswordStrength != "Blank" && result) {` will error if `result==null` as `&&` in js is left-to-right - needs to be `if (result && result.PasswordStrength != "Blank") {`  example to put in console: `var x = null; if (x.test && x) { console.log("x") }`

Comment: Please clarify/confirm: Your Action is getting called, but the `string Password` is always null (or empty string)?

Comment: to confirm the issue is not with my return that all works perfectly when StregthCheck is loaded the parameter password/thePassword is null. What do you mean I don't have password in my result ?

Comment: Thanks for the insight @freedomn-m, off-topic but useful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when nothing worked then use querystring for testing , for this change your url as shown below

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Password").change(function () {
        debugger
        var password = $("#Password").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Login/StrengthCheck?Password='+password ,
            data: {},
            dataType:'json',
          ----
         })
```

Method 2.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Password").change(function () {
            debugger
            var password = $("#Password").val();
            var data={
                       "password" :password ,
                      }
           

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Login/StrengthCheck' ,
                data:Json.Stringify(data),
                dataType:'json',
              ----
             })
```

model binder:- https://www.sharpencode.com/article/MVC/model-binders

Comment: Wow, that worked thanks so much !!! surely this isn't the best practice though? Would it be okay to leave it like this is ina professional environment?

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem arises, the data model comes back with a null password.

Answer (score 0):

HttpPost can receive parameters from the QueryString and the request body.
By default, primitive types are searched in the query string, where complex types are considered to be in the body.

Your method is defined to receive Password from the Query String, not the Body. That's why it stays empty.
You have 2 ways of solving this.

- you change your ajax call so that Password is in the query string.
- you change your method to receive a complex model and leave your ajax

```
public class Model {
  public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for making that extremely teachable. You taught me something new. However, unfortunately before trying to simplify the problem I actually had a model acting like a complex type where I experience the same problem. I have edited the code for the problem please re-analyze it and tell me I've it correct. It is still not working, unfortunately.

Comment: @MatthewLeslie I see some issues, like ```ConfirmPassword``` being required but that's not visible in the ajax (but you are testing and that could have changed already).
In your method you could also check ```ModelState.IsValid``` to see if the model was parsed correctly. ```ModelState``` should also have an indication why the model is wrong

Comment: Hello Kevin, So that ajax is actually executing on a.change function so it's going off before I want to measure the model state. When the button is pressed I measure the modelState and make sure the Confirm password is there.

Comment: @MatthewLeslie ok, we are talking different things here. Modelstate is checked serverside. It's an object in your controller method that gives information on the parsed model and why it is null or failing.

Comment: Okay I see, thanks for that insight I'm going to use it to test now. I've previously only used ModelState to make sure my required fields etc are populated.

Comment: Kevin my model state only gives one error and that's that the password is required and the error message is null.